# How to Make ZURB Foundation Top-Bar Dropdown Menu 100% Width?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

Did some searching but only found info for the megaBar. Would like to have 100% width dropdown widths and implement it with as little css/js on top of Foundation as possible.

I'd like to do a sub menu (ul > li.has-dropdown -> ul.dropdown) that is 100% window width similar to the one on Mashable and shows on hover. The Foundation megaBar is outside of the nested nav structure but that's not what I'd like for my Wordpress template (want to stay in the nested walker type menu tree).

If you hover over any of the top menu links on [Mashable](http://mashable.com), you'll see the dropdown submenu I'd like to copy (just the structure, not the content).

[image: Mashable top menu with dropdown]

I'm using Foundation 3.2 and have the `<div class="contain-to-grid fixed"><nav class="top-bar">` setup so that it is fixed to the top and always 100% window width while the top-bar has a `max-width: 1440px`, just like the Mashable site.

Now I just need the dropdown (sub menu) part sussed out.

Answer (score 5):

This will reset your top bar submenu to be 100% of your top bar's width and will organise your submenu items in responsive columns, just as a flyout content but still preserving the navigation behavior on the small screen size

```
@media only screen and (min-width: $screenSmall) {

    nav.top-bar > section > ul > li.has-dropdown{
        position: static;
        & > .dropdown{
            @include outerRow();

            & > li.has-dropdown{
                @include column(3);
                min-width: auto;

                .dropdown{
                    @include outerRow();
                    position: static;
                    visibility: inherit;
                    top: auto !important;
                    left: auto !important;
                    padding: 0;
                    min-width: auto;
                    li{
                        @include column(12);
                         min-width: auto;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Foundation does come with the functionality for a dropdown menu, so you could replicate the type of navigation used by Mashable with the Foundation framework.

If you read the documentation:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php

You'll see that in the Nav Bar example, Nav Item 4 has a dropdown with its own rows/columns. As per the docs, "You can also have dropdowns with a specific size which can contain any kind of content, including rows and columns."

You should be able to specify the size of the dropdown so that it spans the page, by using CSS to alter the size of the flyout class.

Answer (score 0):

I searched everywhere for an easy answer to making the drop down mega menu 100% of the container and found it here:

http://codepen.io/sldavidson/full/Jseph

The one essential style was this:

```
.open {left: 0 !important;}
```

Answer (score -3):

This UI component is not part of Foundation (see [Foundation Components](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components.php)). As you already mention, the [dropdown menu](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php) is limited to showing nested menu elements.

Creating the same functionality as in the Mashable site is out of the scope of Foundation and will involve developing it by your own. The question is IMHO [not suitable to be answered in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you feel this question is not suitable for stack? The page you linked to does not indicate anything that would disqualify this question.

Comment: @stacko "Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers." There are many different ways to build what you are asking for. Perhaps you could re-ask the question to find _existing_ alternatives outside of ZURB Foundation.

Comment: @NaoiseGolden Aren't there always several ways to build anything?